# How to calculate power index in CMake file

Tags: foreach, cmake, exponentiation

I am working on CMake unit test cases that is using `ctest`.

I am having one question here.

Some part of my CMake is as below:

```
set(size_w   32  )
set(powerof2_w  5 )
foreach(size  ${size_w})
  foreach(pwr_of_2  ${powerof2_w})
    ...
    FUNCTION_EXE(${size} ${pwr_of_2})
  endforeach(pwr_of_2)
endforeach(size)

set(size_w   64  )
set(powerof2_w  6 )
foreach(size  ${size_w})
  foreach(pwr_of_2  ${powerof2_w})
    ...
    FUNCTION_EXE(${size} ${pwr_of_2})
  endforeach(pwr_of_2)
endforeach(size)

set(size_w   128  )
set(powerof2_w  7 )
foreach(size  ${size_w})
  foreach(pwr_of_2  ${powerof2_w})
    ...
    FUNCTION_EXE(${size} ${pwr_of_2})
  endforeach(pwr_of_2)
endforeach(size)

set(size_w   256  )
set(powerof2_w  8 )
foreach(size  ${size_w})
  foreach(pwr_of_2  ${powerof2_w})
    ...
    FUNCTION_EXE(${size} ${pwr_of_2})
  endforeach(pwr_of_2)
endforeach(size)
```

**Expectation:**

I want to reduce that one loop which is with `powerof2_w` parameter:

```
foreach(pwr_of_2  ${powerof2_w})
```

Is it possible to calculate the `pwr_of_2` parameter from the `size_w` parameter inside the `foreach(size  ${size_w})` for-loop itself?

Note: Also, I want to combine all four of these **for-loops** into one **for-loop** using an array index.

Is this possible in CMake?

Comment: Can you please provide a more concrete example of the desired behavior? What is this *supposed* to do? Because the `size_w` and `powerof2_w` parameters are not *lists*, each loop will only have one iteration...

Comment: Because of the limitation of sharing my data ,I would like to explain few things that the `size_w` is the width of my block . and in my code I am calculating the power_of_2 parameter.Its name different in my code.But I need to send that value from cmake only as I do not want to calculate that parameter in my source file .

Comment: Here `size_w` is changing from 32 ,64,128,256,512  ....so `powerof2_w` should be : 5,6,7,8,9

Comment: @squareskittles,Is it possible to combine this (32 ,64,128,256,512) and (5,6,7,8,9 ) loop into one loop but with some condition check .

Comment: @squareskittles,but the pair (32 : 5 ) , (64:6) , (128:7) , (256:8) , (512:9) should go like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to calculate the **exponential** component for the powers of two for the given sizes:

```
32, 64, 128, 256, 512
```

These are powers of two with corresponding exponents of:

```
5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

which we can calculate.

Unfortunately, CMake's [`math()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/math.html) function does not support exponential arithmetic. But luckily, powers of two are easy to manipulate using [bit-shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Logical_shift), which is supported in CMake. We can create a simple CMake function to calculate the (power of 2) exponents used to derive the sizes `32, 64, 128, etc`.

```
function(calc_power_of_two_exponent num exponent)
    set(counter 0)
    # Shift until our number equals 1.
    while(num GREATER 1)
        # Right shift by 1
        math(EXPR num "${num} >> 1")
        # Count the number of times we shift.
        math(EXPR counter "${counter} + 1")
    endwhile()
    # Return the number of times shifted, which is the exponent.
    set(exponent ${counter} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

It looks like you want to iterate through these size and exponent values in pairs. We can set a *list* of sizes to iterate over, and calculate the corresponding exponent as we go.

```
set(sizes 32 64 128 256 512)

# Iterate through each size.
foreach(size ${sizes})
    # Call the function to calculate its base-2 power (or index).
    calc_power_of_two_exponent(${size} exponent)

    message(STATUS "${size} ${exponent}")
    FUNCTION_EXE(${size} ${exponent})
endforeach(size)
```

The status `message` can be used to confirm we pass the correct values to the `FUNCTION_EXE` function. This code prints:

```
32 5
64 6
128 7
256 8
512 9
```

Comment: Yes..This is what I was looking .Shift operations.Thanks you very much .